# Plotting a string of CSV data in realtime using Linux

Tags: linux, plot, real-time, gnuplot, graphite

I have a text file the is continuously updated with sensor data.  Here is a sample:

```
12/28/2012 09:18:11,09:17:12,277.016541,273.457367,2324.178467,0.000000,0.571761,6.648867,6.648867,3.371597,3.371597,0.000000,0.007276,-0.001178,-0.195191,-0.003888,-1.484903,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,288.040405,0.000000,12.074584,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,12.074584,288.040405,1137.196655,0.000000,0.000000
```

I am trying to get some plots generated so I can better see what my data looks like.  The text file is updated every 15 sec or so with new data.  I would like to create one plot with all of the data in it.  Time is the X axis.  I would then like to create a plot with individual sensor data.  I really like Graphite but it does not understand my data stream.  I am playing with gnuplot, but cant seem to get it to plot using my data file.

Any pointers out there?

Comment: get it to work for with 2 fields first? Time and 1 sensor? Good luck.

Comment: gnuplot should be able to dop that. Exactly how, I don't know. You'll probably want a little script that checks if there is a new file, and then replots.

Comment: Thank for the input.  My problem was telling gnuplot that my delimiter was a comma.  Now she is plotting correctly!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up